# if radio button is checked want to open fragment 1 on button click. else open fragment 2 on button click

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, onclicklistener

[image]

when employee radio button is checked on click plus button open fragment1 when position radio is check on click plus button open fragment 2

```
 setCurrentFragment(Fragment1())
        if (binding.incNavToolBar.rbEmployee.isChecked) {
            binding.incNavToolBar.ivToolbarEnd.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(r.id.fragment1)
            }
        }
       
        if (binding.incNavToolBar.rbPosition.isChecked) {
            binding.incNavToolBar.ivToolbarEnd.setOnClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(r.id.fragment2)
            }
        }

private fun setCurrentFragment(currentFragment: Fragment) {
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()
            ?.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerMenu, currentFragment)
            ?.commit()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to assign the action inside the condition, which will not give you dynamic result apart from your initial clicks assignments. To achieve this you have to flip your conditions inside your action, something like this:

```
  binding.incNavToolBar.ivToolbarEnd.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.incNavToolBar.rbEmployee.isChecked) {
                findNavController().navigate(r.id.fragment1)
            } else {
                findNavController().navigate(r.id.fragment2)
            }
        }
```